# Project fail after VS 2019 Community update

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, devexpress

After updating VS 2019 Community to the latest version (16.11.17) my project rebuild works well using the CLI (`msbuild 16.11.2` and `nuget 5.11.2`):

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\MyProject" /t:restore;rebuild`

but it fails using the UI with these errors:

`Error  NU1105  Unable to read project information for 'MyProject': Sequence contains more than one element`

`Error  NETSDK1005  Assets file 'C:\MyProject\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net5.0-windows'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net5.0-windows' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.    MyProject   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.410\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets`

`project.assets.json` content

```json
{
  "version": 3,
  "targets": {},
  "libraries": {},
  "projectFileDependencyGroups": {},
  "packageFolders": {
    "C:\\Users\\Admin\\.nuget\\packages\\": {},
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DevExpress 20.2\\.NET Core Desktop Libraries\\Offline Packages": {},
    "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DevExpress 20.2\\Components\\Offline Packages": {}
  },
  "project": {
    "restore": {
      "projectUniqueName": "C:\\MyProject\\MyProject.csproj",
      "projectPath": "C:\\MyProject\\MyProject.csproj",
      "packagesPath": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\.nuget\\packages\\",
      "outputPath": "C:\\MyProject\\obj\\",
      "projectStyle": "PackageReference",
      "fallbackFolders": [
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DevExpress 20.2\\.NET Core Desktop Libraries\\Offline Packages",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DevExpress 20.2\\Components\\Offline Packages"
      ],
      "configFilePaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\NuGet\\NuGet.Config",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NuGet\\Config\\DevExpress .NET Core Desktop 20.2.config",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NuGet\\Config\\DevExpress 20.2.config",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NuGet\\Config\\DevExpress Cloud.config",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NuGet\\Config\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config"
      ],
      "sources": {
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DevExpress 20.2\\.NET Core Desktop Libraries\\System\\Components\\Packages": {},
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\DevExpress 20.2\\Components\\System\\Components\\Packages": {},
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\NuGetPackages\\": {},
        "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json": {},
        "https://nuget.devexpress.com/MyKey/api": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "logs": [
    {
      "code": "NU1105",
      "level": "Error",
      "message": "Unable to read project information for 'MyProject': Sequence contains more than one element"
    }
  ]
}
```

`MyProject.csproj` content:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFrameworks>net48;net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
        <Platforms>x86</Platforms>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Win" Version="20.2.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.WindowsDesktop.Win" Version="20.2.5-ctp" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Win.Reporting" Version="20.2.5" />
        <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Reporting.Core" Version="20.2.5" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

these files are installed:

- DevExpressComponentsBundleSetup-20.2.5.exe
- DevExpressNetCoreDesktopSetup-20.2.5.exe

`> dotnet --list-sdks` outputs

- 2.1.602 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
- 2.2.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
- 5.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
- 5.0.410 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

I deleted the obj folder then executed `dotnet restore` but the problem persists, how to fix this issue?

Comment: .NET 5 is no longer supported. See the following for more info: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core

Comment: What's the version of your MSBuild dan nuget.exe. You can try to update nuget.exe and MSBuild.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT msbuild 16.11.2 and nuget 5.11.2

Comment: Try to download the latest nuget.exe and clear the NuGet cache then restore the package.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT I tried with `dotnet nuget locals all --clear` and delete .vs bin obj directories

Comment: Have you checked the "Default package management format"? In VS menu, go to Tools => Options... => NuGet Package Manager => General. Under "Package Management" is "Default package management format".